# how to disable #top-chrome-md in chrome v71.0.3578.80

Tags: google-chrome

New chrome v71.0.3578.80 seems remove 'disable' option for 'top-chrome-md'. I tried to disable it, but there no option for it. The new 'top-chrome-md' is really ugly. How can I disable it?

Comment: Chrome has now removed the old Material Design: https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/a384i4/did_google_remove_the_ability_to_disable_material/

Answer (score 0):

You cant anymore as of this update and google has no intention of re-adding it. Either you live with it, revert to an older version or switch browsers